# Very strange unknown crash on iOS with device reboot

Tags: ios, crash, reboot

I cannot suggest any reasons, the situation is following: after long time of playing a game (about 30 mins) iDevice (iPad 2/3/4, iOS 6.0/6.1.3) silently reboots.
Crash log looks very poor:

```
Incident Identifier: 34A0B473-42F7-468B-8C2F-C7285F170BCB
CrashReporter Key:   462b3e4252c67554d7aaeade0c762018e2877eb0
Date: 2013-09-18 17:29:58 +0300
Reset count: 0
Boot failure count: 1
Boot faults: wdog
Boot stage: 255
Boot app: 0
```

There are no memory warnings, from observing we know that there are about 50 opened files at crash moment (but this is not the edge for iOS devices), the game is OpenGL-based.

If anyone has similar "experience" or can propose solution - I would be very thankful. And it would be interesting to know, does anybody meet the similar issue.

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint?

Comment: An exception breakpoint wouldn't fire if the device is hard-reseting.

How much battery does the device have remaining when it resets. Does the device feel warm or even hot to the touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash reason found:
It was caused by `ffmpeg` lib. After updating it from v1.2.1 to v2.0.1 all becomes flawless.
There are thousands of changes so we could not determine exact reason.